# Determining the IP address of neighbors in a wireless mesh

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, udp, mesh-network

I am attempting to create a program for a wireless mesh (adhoc in all but name). Most of the network will deal with TCP messaging but to determine all neighbor IPs (as they will be unknown on startup), I choose to use UDP Broadcast for the initial discovery messages.

I have two problems currently. First, the UDP Broadcast is only being received by the sender and none of its neighbors; second, as the receiving socket can not accept the sender's socket (due to the message being a datagram), I am not able to recover an IP address.

I am in need of a methodology that would allow this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to get the source address along with the datagram via e.g. [recvfrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740120.aspx).  [Here's the .NET version.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdfskwcy.aspx)  You also have to [set a socket option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e160993d.aspx) to send broadcast datagrams.

See also [this question: Broadcasting UDP thru all network cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096142/broadcasting-udp-message-to-all-the-available-network-cards)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the second issue.

Comment: You set the broadcast option, and still can't send a datagram to multiple nodes?

Comment: They were, I had the system parsing them wrong so they weren't showing up as received. Took a while to figure out because no errors or exceptions were showing up anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Why UDP and why not say, ICMP Pings to the broadcast address, or even bruteforcing your way down the netblock with ICMP pings?  It seems to me that a ping would be more appropriate for determining if a specific host is "alive", no?

Comment: Most systems are locked down and only reply to unicast pings.