# Creating a TCP/UDP service on local computer

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want to create a window service (TCP/UDP) based on my local computer. I want to send data to this service from anywhere. Lets suppose I have a static IP (1.2.3.4) and I want to listen at port (4321). My local computer is behind a Router. Router's WAN static IP is (1.2.3.4).

How to create a service for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to check Windows Communication Foundation and host a service in a Windows service.

Check how to do an UDP service with WCF:

- http://dotmad.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-udp-multicast-channel-in-wcf.html

And for TCP, just read this other article:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx

I'll suggest WCF in order to avoid reinventing wheels.

Answer (score 2):

You just create a regular service. If you want to allow access from anywhere, then set up port forwarding on your router.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UdpClient or TcpClient, [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096142/broadcasting-udp-message-to-all-the-available-network-cards). It's another question but there are some snippets you can copy, and it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

As stephen said, use port forwarding.

Here you have a little information on how
http://portforward.com/help/pfprogression.htm