# VB UDP connection from specific local interface

Tags: vb.net, udp, udpclient, network-interface

I am starting out with network programming and networks in general, struggling quite a bit. I would like to make a UDP connection (socket or client) from the ethernet connection on my PC, i.e. NOT the wireless - which goes to the router to the internet.

I would like to send out a message to all devices that might be listening on the network connected at the ethernet network interface and then listen for any answers. I did see multicast mentioned for selecting a specific interface, but dont understand how to use it...

Furthermore, looking at the udpClient I'm not sure how I should listen, or recieve, any responses

Comment: To clarify most of the text of this question is intended to better describe where I am at in my learning curve and why I am attempting to do what I ask, as I dont even know yet if this is the correct way of going about things! My actual question is how to set a UDP connection to use a specific network interface as the local end of a connection instead of other enabled interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I needed to create a UDP socket independent of any client, bind it to the local interface (using bind()) and then set a client to use that socket.

I haven't figured out how to actually do the last bit though (i.e. set a client to use an already created socket) as I was working from a C# example which used syntax that obv wasn't valid in my vb to  do this.

Answer (score 1):

This question is really too broad to be answered.

When sending data like this the framework will pick the appropriate network interface based on the IP you give it. [The accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096142/broadcasting-udp-message-to-all-the-available-network-cards) shows how you can broadcast to all interfaces.

But to get you started try this example project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8877/UDP-Send-and-Receive-using-threads-in-VB-NET

That should cover everything you asked about. If you have more specific questions once you look into the source then post another question.

Comment: well OK my main question was how to select a specific network interface for the local end of a udpclient connection. Will take a look at your link also though.

Comment: this does help, somewha, with the receiving, but has nothing on the setting of network interface to use.