# Why do I get a NullReferenceException from a call to GetIPv4Properties

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, ipv4, network-interface

*Note: I am aware and of full knowledge what a [`NullReferenceException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) is and how to debug and find where it comes from - this is not the question here*

My goal: For a project in Unity3D I am trying to find all my device's network interfaces and store their `IpAddress`es in a list for later usage. Later I will broadcast some message on all of them.

I followed [How do I get the network interface and its right IPv4 address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855230/how-do-i-get-the-network-interface-and-its-right-ipv4-address) and [Broadcasting UDP message to all the available network cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096142/broadcasting-udp-message-to-all-the-available-network-cards) (in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39691081/7111561)) among others and tried to come up with the following:

```
var addresses = new List<IPAddress>();

var allNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

foreach (var networkInterface in allNetworkInterfaces)
{
    if (networkInterface.OperationalStatus != OperationalStatus.Up) continue;
    if (networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 && networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)continue;
    if (!networkInterface.SupportsMulticast) continue;
    if (!networkInterface.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4)) continue;

    var ipProperties = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();
    if (ipProperties == null) continue;

    var ipv4Properties = ipProperties.GetIPv4Properties(); // !! EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE !!
    if (ipv4Properties == null) continue;

    if (NetworkInterface.LoopbackInterfaceIndex == ipv4Properties.Index) continue;
            
    var unicastAddresses = ipProperties.UnicastAddresses;

    foreach (var unicastIpAddressInformation in unicastAddresses)
    {
        if (unicastIpAddressInformation.Address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetwork) continue;

        addresses.Add(unicastIpAddressInformation.Address);
    }
}

// and yes I used Linq before but I converted it to the loop due to debug the exception ^^
```

The exception

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Net.NetworkInformation.Win32IPv4InterfaceProperties.GetPerAdapterInfo(int,System.Net.NetworkInformation.Win32_IP_PER_ADAPTER_INFO,int&)
>
> at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Win32IPv4InterfaceProperties..ctor (System.Net.NetworkInformation.Win32_IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES addr, System.Net.NetworkInformation.Win32_MIB_IFROW mib) [0x00030] in <14e3453b740b4bd690e8d4e5a013a715>:0
>
> at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Win32IPInterfaceProperties2.GetIPv4Properties () [0x00000] in <14e3453b740b4bd690e8d4e5a013a715>:0
>
> at Broadcast.BroadCastTest (System.UInt16 broadcastPort, System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient client) [0x000ae] in C:\xxxxxx\Broadcast.cs:797

is thrown in

```
var ipv4Properties = ipProperties.GetIPv4Properties();
```

where `ipProperties` is **not** `null` so apparently it comes from somewhere inside of [`GetIPv4Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.getipv4properties). The only possibly thrown exception listed in the API would be a `NetworkInformationException` but not a `NullReferenceException`.

Also before I checked and made already sure that

```
networkInterface.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4)
```

is `true` (it's my Ethernet interface so it clearly is an IPv4 interface).

**So why is the exception thrown and how can I solve this?**

Am I doing something stupid? ^^

---

Update

Following the principle, fix it by commenting it out for now I simply skip the loopBack check

```
// var ipv4Properties = ipProperties.GetIPv4Properties();
// if (ipv4Properties == null) continue;

// if (NetworkInterface.LoopbackInterfaceIndex == ipv4Properties.Index) continue;
```

Since afaik the loopback should already be covered since

```
networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback
```

Comment: Interesting problem, and a very frustrating one I'm sure.... Could this be the same as this unity bug? https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/il2cpp-player-crashes-when-ipinterfaceproperties-dot-getipv4properties-is-called-in-an-il2cpp-build

Comment: @Ruzihm hm interesting, might be indeed a bug .. especially since exactly this is used in so many examples .. would be strange if it just fails for me