# SNMP Broadcast in Multiple network interface card installed PC

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

We have laptop installed with two NIC (WLAN and LAN) which connects to different networks. so it has two different IPs.

In this condition, If we perform SNMP broadcast discovery(using 255.255.255.255) to identify the SNMP compliant devices. We get only the device listed in WLAN and LAN interface IP ranges are not detected.
How can I get all the SNMP-compliant devices connected in the WLAN and also LAN network through SNMP broadcast discovery(using 255.255.255.255) ?

Thank you

Comment: How did you send the broadcast request? Via command line or your own code?

Comment: Hi Lex, Broadcast through SharpSNMP library Discovery API

Comment: Since you use #SNMP and .NET has a limitation on how to broadcast, this question is duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096142/broadcasting-udp-message-to-all-the-available-network-cards